# Door jamb and threshold: what goes on top?

Tags: doors, flooring, carpentry

Working on a doorway between two rooms where the floor heights differ by 3/4" so there will be a threshold that spans the two heights. Can't quite decide whether I should install the threshold and then the jambs on top of the threshold, or the jambs first and then fit the threshold between the jambs.

Comment: Jambs on top of threshold gives taller space for door.

Comment: @Kris How so? The space above the threshold is the same regardless

Comment: Assuming your jambs are precut to length